# Adding ffmpeg to to docker(Alpine base image)

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, dockerfile, digital-ocean, alpine-linux

I am trying to add FFmpeg into my docker container with an alpine base image. I am getting this error

```
2021-10-26 13:45:42] ffmpeg version 4.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   built with gcc 9.2.0 (Alpine 9.2.0)
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   configuration: --prefix=/usr --enable-avresample --enable-avfilter --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-postproc --enable-pic --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-libxcb --disable-stripping --disable-static --disable-librtmp --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libopus --disable-debug
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42]   libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[2021-10-26 13:45:42] [NULL @ 0x7fd61378e180] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'yarn'
[2021-10-26 13:45:42] yarn: Invalid argument
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:erbium-alpine

ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app/

RUN apk upgrade -U \ 
    && apk add ca-certificates ffmpeg libva-intel-driver \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/*

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile && \
    yarn cache clean

EXPOSE 3030
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/ffmpeg"] 
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) you are not saying if you get the problem when building your image or running a container out of it. From my understanding this is when running (indicating that installing ffmpeg is not the issue) but you should be more explicit about this in your question (=> [edit](/posts/69724395/edit)). 2) your `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` settings are basically configuring your image to run the following default command on container start: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg yarn start`. Unless I've been away far too long, this cannot work. Please edit your question and explain what you are trying to acheive exactly.

Comment: The behavior of having both `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` together hasn't changed, and as @Zeitounator indicates these get combined together to form the single command to run.  See [Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) in the Dockerfile documentation.

Comment: @Zeitounator , @ David Maze
Thanks for your response. I realized I do not need the ENTRYPOINT, so I deleted it and everything is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by deleting the ENTRYPOINT because I realized I do not need it. And in my code I am spinning ffmpeg as a child process